# Using data in a .csv file to replace words in a .txt file

Tags: r, csv, replace

I have a .csv (lets call it TL.csv) file with two columns of data that follow this pattern:

```
A1 B1
A2 B2
A3 B3
etc
```

I would like to have a script to run in R Studio that will run through various .txt files (lets use a hypothetical file, TEST.txt) and replace all instances of A1 with B1, all instances of A2 with B2, all instances of A3 with B3, etc, and do this for the entire document. Then I'd like to have the modified .txt file (say named TESTOUTPUT.txt).

So far, with my extremely rudimentary skills, I've been able to piece together some incomplete code that probably wont work but I feel was worth an attempt.

So I've put my TL.csv file and TEST.txt

```
setwd("C:/Users/Alex/Documents/RWork")
TLData<-read.csv(file="TL.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
```

For context I have a wikidot website I use to keep information about a tabletop RPG I run, and I would like to be able to add hovertext definitions to terms when Im writing pages. Like when a Talent appears in the talents/stats section of an NPC I want to replace it with

```
[[span class="hover"]] Talent [[span]] Definition [[/span]][[/span]]
```

so my players or I can hover our mouse over the Talent and see the Definition without having to look it up.

If anyone could help me write this code I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: It would be helpful if you could show your expected output too.

Comment: I've uploaded the .csv file I'll be using on Google Drive
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gIJz2zwXdTdvfE5hiqj-KDpA8N0pSZ-9/view?usp=sharing
and an example .txt file like the type I'd like to run the script on to modify
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1jDVrtAiJt9kzvnds-pZIvxmEgEjfIsyN
I essentially want to use the .csv file as something I can run on text files after I write them.

Answer (score 0):

```r
library(readr)
library(stringr)

notional_csv <- c(
"A1, B1
A2, B2
A3, B3"
)


df <- notional_csv %>%                   # replace with path to your .csv
  read_csv(col_names = c("text_to_replace", "replacement")) # you should already have column names

df
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   text_to_replace replacement
#>   <chr>           <chr>      
#> 1 A1              B1         
#> 2 A2              B2         
#> 3 A3              B3

# the .csv is read in as a data frame, use it to create a named vector:
replacements <- df$replacement %>%        
  `names<-`(df$text_to_replace)

replacements
#>   A1   A2   A3 
#> "B1" "B2" "B3"

# an example string
string <- "This is the A1 sentence. This is the A2 sentence. Here's the A3 sentence"

string
#> [1] "This is the A1 sentence. This is the A2 sentence. Here's the A3 sentence"

# replace based on the named values in the replacements vector
new_string <- str_replace_all(string, replacements)

new_string
#> [1] "This is the B1 sentence. This is the B2 sentence. Here's the B3 sentence"

# whatever the path/directory is you're using
temp_path <- paste0(tempdir(), "/TEST.txt")

# write the string to TEST.txt
write_lines(new_string, path = temp_path)

# Check it by reading TEST.txt back into R
read_lines(temp_path)
#> [1] "This is the B1 sentence. This is the B2 sentence. Here's the B3 sentence"
```